# .NET Core 6 Web Application Azure B2C Error - OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler message.State is null or empty

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure AD B2C authentication setup in my .Net Core 6 MVC application, which is working for the most part in my localhost and development server.

However when I have a trailing slash in my Dev website URL (sample URL below) it is showing an error message. So after removing the trailing slash everything works just fine.

- `https://developmenturl.test.net/TEST` --> *This always works*
- `https://developmenturl.test.net/TEST/` --> *This always breaks!*

Please note above, my dev URL has a path (TEST) after the hostname.

Interesting thing is, when I put a trailing slash and do a fiddler trace it is not even going to the *on.microsoft*... URL. But the URL without slash always takes me to *on.microsoft* (Azure B2C).

When the trailing slash is there in the URL, Seems like application just breaks in the app.start() & shows the error below.

> **Error.** An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID:
> 00-dfsdfskddkdkkdkdhjuuede-kkdlfssdfkskdlfds-00
>
> Details **OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler**: message.**State is null or
> empty.**

My appsettings.json

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
"CallbackPath": "/",
"Instance": "https://<company name>.b2clogin.com",
"ClientId": "*******",
"Domain": "<companyname>.onmicrosoft.com",
"ClientSecret": "*******",
"SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/b2c_<company specific>_susi",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_<company specific>_susi",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_<company specific>_pwss",
}
```

My Startup.cs ConfigureServices() method (Tried with and without OpenIdConnectOptions. Behaves the same):

```
////=================AzureB2C ============//
        services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C)
                 .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { })
                 .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddOptions();
       
        //services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//----////============END AzureB2C ============//-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your configuration doesn't seem to be a problem ,but your problem is a little strange.  `An error occurred while processing your request` is common in environment development problems, while `message.State is null or empty` is common in Authentication login.

Comment: Make sure `app.UseAuthentication();` comes after `app.UseRouting`. Have a look at setting the environment to Development, to enable the default [Developer Exception Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Set a breakpoint in your action, call the page again and see what's wrong.

Comment: @Chen app.UseRouting() and app.UseAuthentication() were already in correct order. 

An Update: When I use "CallbackPath": "/" in my local appsettings.json file it shows the exact same behavior as my Dev Environment. When I remove "CallbackPath": "/" localhost works just fine. So it is JUST the callbackpath which is causing all this I believe.

Comment: Any one has any ideas? Still has this issue.

Comment: Are you logging in with a social account? If so, have you added your callback URL to the list of supported redirect URLs on the appropriate app? Perhaps the trailing slash needs to be added there as another entry.

Comment: No I am not using a social account for logging in.